# Problem sending email using ssmtp

Tags: smtp, ssmtp, gmail

I am attempting to setup so I can mail from Raspbian.

When I attempt to send I get an error `ssmtp: Cannot open smtp.gmail.com:587` (I also tried port:465)

I have set "Access for less secure apps" on Google and can send/receive from the account on Thunderbird.

I have installed `ssmtp` and configured `/etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf` to contain:-

```
# Config file for sSMTP sendmail
#
# The person who gets all mail for userids < 1000
# Make this empty to disable rewriting.
root=xxxxxx.raspberry.pi@gmail.com

# The place where the mail goes. The actual machine name is required no 
# MX records are consulted. Commonly mailhosts are named mail.domain.com
mailhub=smtp.gmail.com:587

AuthUser=xxxxxx.raspberry.pi@gmail.com
AuthPass=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
UseTLS=YES
UseSTARTTLS=YES

# Where will the mail seem to come from?
rewriteDomain=gmail.com

# The full hostname
hostname=xxxxxx.raspberry.pi@gmail.com

# Are users allowed to set their own From: address?
# YES - Allow the user to specify their own From: address
# NO - Use the system generated From: address
FromLineOverride=YES
```

I have also configured `/etc/ssmtp/revaliases` to contain:-

```
# sSMTP aliases
# 
# Format:   local_account:outgoing_address:mailhub
#
# Example: root:your_login@your.domain:mailhub.your.domain[:port]
# where [:port] is an optional port number that defaults to 25.
root:xxxxxx.raspberry.pi@gmail.com:smtp.gmail.com:587
```

Any suggestions?

---

Edit
The settings above based on  https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SSMTP

I have done some further testing.

1. I selected a different SMTP server, which worked. (I do not want to use this, as it is only available when directly connected to my ISP.)
2. I tried setting an Application Specific password, and got the response"The setting you are looking for is not available for your account". (Presumably because this account does not have 2-factor authentication.)

The gmail account I am trying to use was specifically created to send messages from the Raspberry Pi.

Comment: Setting up an application password is one of the ways, as far as I can remember; it has been a good while ago.

Comment: `Cannot open` sounds like a network level issue, can you use tcpdump or wireshark to see if the packets are even getting to google?

Comment: @tripleee I changed the `hostmail` and it **worked**. If you post as answer I will accept! I had used a guide from a reputable book, which had a full example, and this used email address! The Arch site said "# The full hostname.  Must be correctly formed, fully qualified domain name or GMail will reject connection.
hostname=yourlocalhost.yourlocaldomain.tld" but I misread this, as email.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `hostname` assignment looks wrong. You probably want `hostname=raspberry.pi` or something like that. (Ideally, your host has a public DNS name, and you should use that.)  It should not be an email address.

Comment: I have not examined the sources but I imagine it's only actually used in the HELO/EHLO in which case it doesn't crucially matter what exactly you put there.  It will end up in a `Received:` header so it's helpful if it somehow uniquely identifies your host.

Comment: The various settings I used actually appeared in Received:, although my ISP removed the `@` and substituted `?`. Google just refused the request. I am now using my domain name.

Answer (score 3):

This is very easy to accomplish:

```
 https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/363814/simplest-way-to-send-one-line-mail-out-via-command-line-using-gmail/363815#363815
```

EXCERPT:

Install `ssmtp` with the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ssmtp
```

Then go into '/etc/ssmtp' and edit 'ssmtp.conf' to look like this:

```
root=rpi3abc@gmail
mailhub=smtp.gmail.com:465
FromLineOverride=YES
AuthUser=rpi3abc@gmail.com
AuthPass=testing123
UseTLS=YES
```

Send a one-liner like so:

```
echo "Testing...1...2...3" | ssmtp myusername@gmail.com
```

Couldn't be simpler.